# Haskell - binding a mapped monadic function

Tags: haskell, io, monads

Within this block of code here, I have a function tagsort that takes a FilePath and returns an IO String.

```
   builddir xs = do
    writeto  <- lastest getArgs
    let folderl b = searchable <$> (getPermissions b)
    let filel   c = ((lastlookup mlookup c) &&) <$> ((not <$> folderl c))
    a <- listDirectory xs
    listdirs <- filterM (folderl) (map ((xs ++ "/") ++) a)
    filedirs <- filterM (filel)   (map ((xs ++ "/") ++) a)
    tagfiles <- tagsort <$> filedirs
--testprint to terminal
    putStrLn $ concat listdirs
    putStrLn $ concat tagfiles


tagsort :: Control.Monad.IO.Class.MonadIO m => FilePath -> m [Char]
tagsort xs = do
    nsartist <- getTags xs artistGetter
    nsalbum  <- getTags xs albumGetter
    let artist = init $ drop 8 $ show nsartist
    let album  = init $ drop 7 $ show nsalbum
    pure (artist ++ " - " ++ album)
```

I'd like to take this function and map it over a list of directories. When run, I get this error.

```
• Couldn't match type ‘[]’ with ‘IO’
      Expected type: IO (t0 [Char])
        Actual type: [t0 [Char]]
    • In a stmt of a 'do' block: tagfiles <- tagsort <$> filedirs
```

I believe I understand what is happening here. In order to bind in the way I desire to tagfiles, I would want an `IO [String]`, but instead mapping tagsort to the list filedirs produces `[IO String]`. I am not totally sure how to circumvent this or if it is even able to be circumvented at all. Perhaps mapping is not the correct way to do this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like you need [sequence](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:sequence). Or just use `mapM` instead of `fmap` / `<$>`

Comment: I swore I tried mapM and it gave the same error as map, but I was wrong. I feel very foolish.

Comment: can you please add the information that it now worked to the question or answer your own question or accept an answer that has been posted instead of just saying that you solved it in the comments

Answer (score 2):

This is because the function `tagsort` is of type `String -> IO String`
Note: I am using `IO` for simplicity and `String` for both `[Char]` and `FilePath`.

However, when mapping it onto `filedir :: [String]` using

```
(<$>) = fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

a conflict occured between `IO [String]` and `[IO String] - the former is what the compiler expects an expression in a do block to be.

This isn't very useful on first glance. However, haskell has a function called `sequence` for this exact task. Its constraints needn't matter much now, as `Foldable` is something completely different. For now, know that it can be of type `[IO a] -> IO [a]`

Luckily again, there's a very useful predefined utility function, `mapM` just for `sequence . map f`.

The final code will be:

```
mapM tagSort fileDirs
```